# How can I get the (real) HTTP response status code from a CORS request in AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

I have a frontend project using AngularJS 1.5.8, which communicates with an API in PHP (Laravel framework). Preflight OPTIONS requests are going as expected, but I'm facing a problem now because I need to know when requests specifically fail with a status code of `401 Unauthorized`.

Through `$http(request).then(successFn, errorFn)`, when `errorFn` is called, it has a single Object argument, whose status is `-1`. When I inspect the Network tab on Chrome developer tools, the request clearly fails, as expected, with `401`. **Is there a way to get this real status code inside the javascript?** I've seen some related questions and answers but most were regarding older versions of angular (in which you had the `.success` method being called with multiple arguments, including status).

Am I missing something on the API side, with CORS? Or is it an AngularJS restriction? I tested it with Postman too, and it brings the correct status code, and even a whole JSON object, with `message` and `debug` properties (none of which shows up in that Network tab of Chrome).

Comment: No. The browser is blocking the response because it violates [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The backend needs to respond to the OPTIONS request with proper CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @georgeawg. Indeed I had to make changes to the backend and now it responds with the proper CORS headers even when an HttpException is thrown. That was the missing case (the response to the OPTIONS request was ok, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being given a little nudge in the right direction, I found out how to fix this problem between the front and back ends of my project. In Laravel file `api_routes.php`, I was inserting CORS as a middleware to each group, as in:

```
$api->group([ 'middleware' => ['cors'] ], function($api) {
    // ...
});
```

This didn't ensure the CORS response headers to be included when requests went bad. So although the browser caught a status code `401` (or anything else), Angular complained something about missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, thus the response object in javascript was pretty useless (it had no `data`, `status` was `-1`, and `statusText` was empty).

By [setting CORS as a global middleware](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/89#issuecomment-175329067) on my Laravel project, all necessary headers began showing up, even on error responses like `401`.

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        // ...
    ];
    // ...
}
```

The response object then became actually useful as it all the forementioned properties as specified on the API and I managed to do what I needed with the status code.

Maybe this helps someone on a similar situation. Be aware, though, as it's a global setting, these headers might show up in responses you didn't intend them to. If anyone knows a more precise way, it'd be great!